# Extracting all post in jagi astronomy

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a collection in mongodb named post.I want to extract all the post id which are not disabled from that collection.I have used jagi astronomy a package of meteor js to create the schema.When i am using the code:-

```
let post=Post.findOne({'disabled':false});
console.log(post._id);
```

In the above case it shows the id of only one post not of all.

While using

```
let post=Post.find({'disabled':false});
console.log(post._id)
```

It is showing undefined.
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting undefined because **[`find()`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-find)** returns a [cursor](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#mongo_cursor). It does not immediately access the database or return documents. [Cursors](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#mongo_cursor) provide **[`fetch()`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-fetch)** to return all matching documents, **[`map()`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-map)** and **[`forEach()`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-forEach)** to iterate over all matching documents, and **[`observe`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-observe)** and **[`observeChanges`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-observeChanges)** to register callbacks when the set of matching documents changes.

In this case you need to call **[`fetch()`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-fetch)** on the cursor to all matching documents as an Array i.e.

```
let posts=Post.find({'disabled':false}).fetch();
console.log(posts[0]._id) // log the first element in the results set
```

or using **[`forEach()`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-forEach)** to iterate the cursor:

```
Post.find({'disabled':false}).forEach(post => console.log(post._id));
```